# Failure when connecting iOS app to Database using Alamofire

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am trying to complete my user registration from my app.

Using Alamofire I am trying to connect my iOS app to my database via my php files/server - yet I am receiving this error message:

> FAILURE: responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}))

**this is my code -**

```
import Alamofire
import UIKit

class SignUpComplete: UIViewController {
    let URL_USER_REGISTER = "https:/mooverdata345.co.uk/registerIPHONE.php";

    @IBOutlet var Email: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var Password: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var Username: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var Firstname: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var Surname: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var HouseNo: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var Postcode: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var labelMessage: UILabel!

    @IBAction func submit(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let parameters: Parameters=[
            "Email":Email.text!,
            "Password":Password.text!,
            "Firstname":Firstname.text!,
            "Surname":Surname.text!,
            "HouseNo":HouseNo.text!,
            "Postcode":Postcode.text!
        ]

        Alamofire.request(URL_USER_REGISTER, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON
            {
                response in
                //printing response
                print(response)

                //getting the json value from the server
                if let result = response.result.value {

                    //converting it as NSDictionary
                    let jsonData = result as! NSDictionary

                    //displaying the message in label
                    self.labelMessage.text = jsonData.value(forKey: "message") as! String?
                }
        }
    }

}
```

I think it may be something to do with JSON. The SQL queries are working so the backend stuff is okay. And my mate's Android app is connecting okay.

Comment: It would appear that your server is not sending back a JSON response, but something else.

Comment: @rmaddy is wright. Also I think jsonData is Array of NSDictionary. try this: let jsonData = result as! [NSDictionary]